# Declaring length of an array with a strlen function

Tags: c, arrays

I was making a program to print your initials (ex. Name:Ben vdr Output:BVDR) and was having trouble with this array

```
string s[strlen(s)] = get_string();
```

I was getting this error

> initials.c:8:21: error: use of undeclared identifier 's'
>       string s[strlen(s)] = get_string();

How would I get this to work?

Comment: Pulling out my crystal ball here, is this a CS50 question?

Comment: What is `get_string()`? What is `string`? (If this is a CS50 question, then `string` is probably a typedef for `char*` -- which is a bad idea, since a string is not a pointer.

Comment: Yes this is a CS50 Question, am I allowed to use stack overflow for questions like this?

Comment: suggest cs50.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

The code makes no sense.

- <s>VLAs are not valid C++</s> (oops, you’re using C)
- Either you are eclipsing some *other* `s` with a new `s` variable, or
- You are trying to use `s` before it is properly scoped (must be *after* the equal sign)
- Arrays are zero-indexed, so assigning to element 100 of a 100-element array is a fencepost error.
- <s>`strlen()` works over C-strings, not `std::string`.</s> (ditto)

As mentioned by **M.M**, if you are only getting a *single* string, do just that:

```
char* s = get_string();  // get_string() malloc()s a proper char array
...
free( s );
```

If you wish to declare an *array* of strings, do so and initialize the array properly:

```
const unsigned N = 100;
char* s[ N ] = { get_string(), "" };  // first elt is copy, all others are empties
```

or

```
char* s[ N ] = { get_string() };  // N copies of result
```

Again, don’t forget to free() exactly that string, exactly *once:*

```
free( s[0] );
```

If you wish to create an array of strings for every character in the c-string `s`, you’ll have to do that in multiple steps.

```
char* p = get_string();
char* ss[ strlen( p ) ] = { NULL };  // VLA
...
free( p );
```

or

```
char* p = get_string();
char** ss = malloc( strlen( p ) * sizeof( char* ) );  // dynamic
...
free( ss );
free( p );
```

Comment: OP error message indicates that this is a C question (source filename ends in `.c`)

Comment: Oops, yes, OP’s use of “string” threw me. I’ll revise after work today.

Answer (score 0):

The length of an array must be known at the point of declaring it. Also, arrays cannot be returned from functions.

Normally the way to input a string of unknown length is to use dynamic allocation inside the `get_string` function. Then the function returns a pointer to the first character of the dynamically allocated block.

The calling code looks like:

```
char *s = get_string();
// ... use s ...
free(s);   // release the dynamically allocated block
```

Answer (score -3):

You can't get the length of `s` before (or as) it is being declared.  You probably want to do something like:

```
string tmp = get_string();
string s[strlen(tmp)] = tmp;
```

Comment: what is `string`?